# Получение заголовка в соответствующей кодировке

Tags: php, кодировка, перекодировка

Имеется задача получать значение тега `title` html документа и выводить пользователю. Всё бы ничего, с сайтами в UTF-8 всё хорошо, но сайтов то в интернете много. Далеко не все из них в UTF-8 и очень многие выводятся кракозябрами. Подскажите верный путь, как можно получить значение `title` и вывести его на русском (если оно на русском) или на английском без кракозябр?
 Вот как я пытался решить эту проблему

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $content = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);

preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $content, $matches);

$detect = mb_detect_encoding($title, mb_detect_order(), true);
        $title = iconv($detect, "utf-8", $matches[1]);
        echo $title;
```

Comment: Может проще будет кинуть get-запрос на страницу и спарсить title?

Comment: и в чем вопрос?....

Comment: Узнать есть ли какой-то способ получать title страницы без кракозябр

Answer (score 1):

Можно вместе с **title** *парсить* значение `<meta charset="">` - и в дальнейшем конвертировать **title** с помощью этого значения в `utf-8`, или использовать его для задания кодировки страницы - в зависимости от ваших задач.